# insert sql record by command line ssh

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh

i try to execute this command line:

```
 ssh root@ip "mysql -u login -ppassword zabbix -e 
'INSERT INTO worldmap_latlng (lat,lng,name,value,timestamp) 
 VALUES (48.891198, 2.2465829, "'test'", 0, now())'"
```

but i have this response :

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'
```

i try with ' and " but not work

Comment: it looks like you didn't select a database

Comment: i select the database zabbix, when i put a number instead of 'test' that work

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using ssh and bash combo

1. write bash file on remote machine say insert.sh in ./ path location

```sh
#!/bin/bash
lat= echo $1
lng= echo $2
name= echo $3
value= echo $4
# echo $lat
# echo $lng
# echo $name
# echo $value
echo "insert into worldmap_latlng (lat,lng,name,value) values $lat , '$lng', '$name' , '$value'  ;"  #| mysql -ulogin -ppassword zabbix
exit
```

2. `ssh root@ip sh ./insert.sh latval lngval nameval valueval`

You can also write some python or other languages script that takes args and insert and execute that using ssh